# Is there a way to deploy Strapi project without admin panel?

Tags: node.js, deployment, server, web-deployment, strapi

As Strapi official docs point:

> At the moment, deploying the Strapi Admin interface requires more than 1g of RAM.

Though in my project, I need only some basic actions with the server (like adding and viewing content), and I already do this via HTTP requests to api. So I would like to deploy only the "api" part itself and not admin panel logic. This way I can save resources & money. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check  [Deploy the administration panel and the plugins on another server than the API](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/admin-panel/deploy.html#deploy-the-administration-panel-and-the-plugins-on-another-server-than-the-api)

## You can just delete the **build** folder. You do not need an admin panel.

Your REST or GraphQL API will work as the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only by making big changes to the main module of Strapi, after that you won’t be able to properly manage the permissions system and other main components, you will also lose the possibility of updates.

update
You can just make all configuration and remove web part from hosting